# unique_base option of sluggable exention doesn't accept a foreign key

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, slug

I have entity **Store** and entity **Category** and each Store can add his own categories.

I'd like to generate **an unique Slug** for each Category based on foreign key **store_id**. I tried using "unique_base" option but it doesn't work.

Why the **"unique_base"** option of Sluggable extension does not accept a foreign key ?

```
class Category
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $name;


/**
* @Gedmo\slug(fields={"name"}, unique_base="store")
* @ORM\Column(name="slug",length=255, unique=false)
*/
private $slug ;

/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Project\StoreBundle\Entity\Store", inversedBy="categories", cascade={"persist"})
* @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
*/
private $store ;

//.................

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [Sluggable Docs](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/sluggable.md) you need to use `RelativeSlugHandler:` to handle foreign-keys